# Does CToolbar support buttons with 32 bit icons?

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc

**Problem:**
Adding 32bit icons to a CToolbar instance seems not to work properly
(quality of image changes).

I encountered in the WEB 2 categories of topics, related to my issue:

- 1-st tells how to add 32 bit images to CToolBar
- 2-nd (actually    one page from MSDN documentation) that "CToolBar
  supports bitmaps    with a maximum of 16 colors" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69wz6ea1.aspx)

it is strange that "16 colors" is mentioned in documentation, not 2^16 colors,
so I might interpreted that information wrongly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `CToolBar::LoadBitmap` you'll see that the bitmaps are loaded using `AfxLoadSysColorBitmap`. A quick look at that function shows that the color table is fixed at 16 colors.

```
// make copy of BITMAPINFOHEADER so we can modify the color table
const int nColorTableSize = 16;
```

As with most things in MFC you probably *could* make it load a 32-bit bitmap if you override enough methods but as you've probably been seeing elsewhere you really want to be using `CMFCToolBar` not just for the support for higher color depths but also many other improved features.

Comment: Does that number '16' stand for the number of colors or the number of bits? I am aware of a CMFCToolbar, but due to I am working with a legacy project, it will be very painful to replace all occurrence of CToolbar with improved version. By the way, thank you for the answer, you gave me useful info & proved my concerns! P.S. I hate MFC functionality & especially documentation, if I were allowed to use Qt - I should do it immediately ))

Answer (score 1):

For quite some time CToolBar has supported images via image lists.

So the trick to load the default 16 colour image that is part of the toolbar resource and then to create image lists at any colour depth before assigning them to the toolbar via the contained CToolBarCtrl.

ie.

```
if (m_toolbar.LoadToolBar(IDR_MAINFRAME))
{
   // create imagelist
   if (m_imageList.Create(....))
   {
      m_toolbar.GetToolBarCtrl().SetImageList(&m_ilNormal);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use CMFCToolBar: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb984480.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the proposition, but I don't see how you answer addresses my question.